# Issue with SBOS ACCELERATORS module

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

in my sitecore instance i install SOLS ACCELERATORS Module,

when I verify my showconfig in /admin/showconfig.aspx

i found this error message 
*error on line 2383 at column 612: Extra happy at the end of the document*

in app_config/include/Sitecore.SBOSAccelerators.config

I removed the following line

```
<pageextenders> 
       <pageextender type="Sitecore.SbosAccelerators.Shared.PageExtenders.InsertAnalyticsDataExtender, Sitecore.SbosAccelerators" /> 
     </ pageextenders>
```

the showconfig.aspx works well

I tried to analyze the code of InsertAnalyticsDataExtender, but I found nothing until now, 
someone already has this kind of problem?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok that's fixed,

the author of SOLS ACCELERATORS Module, verify if the context of the current Site is not Shell or Sheel_Module beffor adding a hidden field with this ID "SC_ANALYTICS_PAGE"

but what happen if the contentType of the page is an XML or a json for example

in this case i'm going to have an error,

to fixe this issue just create a new class in your solution, inherite from

Sitecore.SbosAccelerators.Shared.PageExtenders.InsertAnalyticsDataExtender

add this methode to your class

> public override void Insert()
>           {
>
> // you can replace Context.Site.Name by Context.Page.Page.Response.ContextType=="Text/Xml"
>
> ```
>         if (Context.Site.Name == "admin")
>             return;
>         base.Insert();
>     }
> ```

after that go to Sitecore.SBOSAccelerators.Config and  change your pageextender to use the new class

happy conding

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the part of the configuration directly from your config file, you have a type in the config. You **cannot** close any tag with whitespace at the beginning of the closing tags like this `</ pageextenders>`. Try without the space `</pageextenders>`:

```xml
<pageextenders> 
   <pageextender type="Sitecore.SbosAccelerators.Shared.PageExtenders.InsertAnalyticsDataExtender, Sitecore.SbosAccelerators" /> 
 </pageextenders>
```

Comment: i have do that, but it not working ,
i think this is an issue with this class Sitecore.SbosAccelerators.Shared.PageExtenders.InsertAnalyticsDataExtender, 
i'm going to install this module with a new sitecore Instance, and verify if it will work fine or not